# Magento2: How to add info promo block on top website

Tags: magento2

I want add on our website promo block on the top website every page.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me how to do it?

@update

When I select display block on top header then this block covered the part of my block that I already had. How should I add it to be at the very top and not cover other blocks?
[image]

@update2

Here is source code this block

```
<div class="top-header-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                    <!-- Static block: header_8_top_left_link -->
                                            <div class="top-custom-link">
                            <ul>
<li><a href="mailto:info@czasowewyprzedaze.pl"><span class="icon pe-7s-mail"> </span>info@czasowewyprzedaze.pl</a></li>
<li><a href="https://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/sales/order/history/"><span class="pe-7s-car"> </span>Śledzenie zamówienia</a></li>
<li><a href="https://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/storelocator"><span class="pe-7s-map-marker"> </span>Lokalizator sklepu</a></li>
</ul>
<div>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #b07800;"><a href="https://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/customer/account/create/"><span style="color: #b07800;"><b>Zarejestruj konto</b></span></a> aby otrzymać 100 monet na start!</span></p>
</div>                        </div>
                                    </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs col-xs-12">
                            <div class="dropdown dropdown-switcher language switcher-language" id="switcher-language">
                                                                                                                    <button class="switcher-toggle dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Poland                  <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li class="view-en switcher-option">
                        <a href="#" data-post='{"action":"https:\/\/czasowewyprzedaze.pl\/?___store=en&amp;___from_store=pl","data":{"___store":"en","uenc":"aHR0cHM6Ly9jemFzb3dld3lwcnplZGF6ZS5wbC8,"}}'>
                            <img alt="en" src="https://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/images/flags/en.png" />English                      </a>
                    </li>
                                                                <li class="view-fr switcher-option">
                        <a href="#" data-post='{"action":"https:\/\/czasowewyprzedaze.pl\/?___store=fr&amp;___from_store=pl","data":{"___store":"fr","uenc":"aHR0cHM6Ly9jemFzb3dld3lwcnplZGF6ZS5wbC8,"}}'>
                            <img alt="fr" src="https://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/images/flags/fr.png" />French                       </a>
                    </li>
                                                                <li class="view-de switcher-option">
                        <a href="#" data-post='{"action":"https:\/\/czasowewyprzedaze.pl\/?___store=de&amp;___from_store=pl","data":{"___store":"de","uenc":"aHR0cHM6Ly9jemFzb3dld3lwcnplZGF6ZS5wbC8,"}}'>
                            <img alt="de" src="https://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/images/flags/de.png" />German                       </a>
                    </li>
                                                                <li class="view-it switcher-option">
                        <a href="#" data-post='{"action":"https:\/\/czasowewyprzedaze.pl\/?___store=it&amp;___from_store=pl","data":{"___store":"it","uenc":"aHR0cHM6Ly9jemFzb3dld3lwcnplZGF6ZS5wbC8,"}}'>
                            <img alt="it" src="https://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/images/flags/it.png" />Italy                        </a>
                    </li>
                                                                                            <li class="view-ru switcher-option">
                        <a href="#" data-post='{"action":"https:\/\/czasowewyprzedaze.pl\/?___store=ru&amp;___from_store=pl","data":{"___store":"ru","uenc":"aHR0cHM6Ly9jemFzb3dld3lwcnplZGF6ZS5wbC8,"}}'>
                            <img alt="ru" src="https://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/images/flags/ru.png" />Rusia                        </a>
                    </li>
                                                                <li class="view-at switcher-option">
                        <a href="#" data-post='{"action":"https:\/\/czasowewyprzedaze.pl\/?___store=at&amp;___from_store=pl","data":{"___store":"at","uenc":"aHR0cHM6Ly9jemFzb3dld3lwcnplZGF6ZS5wbC8,"}}'>
                            <img alt="at" src="https://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/images/flags/at.png" />Austria                      </a>
                    </li>
                                    </ul>
    </div>
                                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is theme.less

```
// HEADER 
.header {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    .close-nav-button {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: auto;
        left:-40px;
        z-index: 99999;
        background: none;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        opacity:0;
        .transition( all .3s);
        span {
            display: block;
        }
    }
    .top-header-content {
        background-color: #f6f6f8;
        font-size: 12px;
        clear: both;
        a, button {
            color: #878787;
            &:hover, &:focus {
                color: @base-color;
            }
        }
        .top-middle-header {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 0;
        }
    }
    .dropdown-switcher {
        float: right;
        margin-left: 30px;
        position: static;
        .dropdown-menu {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            .border-radius(0);
            .transition(all 300ms);
            .transform(translateY(20px));
            border: none;
            box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            right: 15px;
            left: auto;
            font-size: 12px;
            min-width: 110px;
            li > a {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
                color: #8e8e8e;
                padding: 8px 15px;
                background: none;
                white-space: nowrap;
                &:hover {
                    color: @base-color;
                }
                img {
                    height: auto;
                    margin-right: 7px;
                    margin-top: -4px;
                    width: 16px;
                }
            }
        }
        .switcher-toggle {
            background: none;
            border: none;
            box-shadow: none;
            font-weight: 400;
            padding: 14px 0;
            position: relative;
            .fa-angle-down {
                font-size: 11px;
                margin-left: 2px;
                margin-top: 1px;
            }
        }
        &.open .dropdown-menu {
            .transform(translateY(0));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create widget and call it page top like below:

Create a widget by below steps:

1. Login to admin.
2. Goto Content > Widgets and then add widget
3. Choose your theme and type CMS Static Block
4. Under layout updates you need to select the following:
   a) Display on: All Pages
   b) Container: Page Top
5. Under **Widget Options** select your promo static block.

Comment: @Sakumar, I have  update my topic.

Comment: That is a css issue. You need to manage it through css. Issue is because you header is absolute or fixed position.

Comment: I have update my topic again. Do you have any solution how I should change in css?

Comment: Wait let me check. Can you share your url?

Comment: czasowewyprzedaze.pl

Comment: This is the right? Zarejestruj konto aby otrzymać 100 monet na start!

Comment: It was in the old block. In a moment, try to turn on the new block then you will see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83148/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-sylvester).